# Comparing Images in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to make a application in android that will compare a image with all the other images in a specific folder.If the image matches with any other image it should identify these as similar images.I have searched a lot but havent found anything concrete or a good base to start with.Are there any libraries using which this can be achieved?Does anyone know how can this be done?Any help will be highly appreciable.Or can someone tell me how can i compare whether 2 images are similar or not .I am a newbie in android and any help would be a good start.Thanks.

Comment: Search for OpenCV. This lib can do the magic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [OpenCV](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki) can do that for you.

In fact, we already had several [discussions about this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bopencv%5D%20compare%20images).

Comment: Hey karlphilip thanks for letting me know that this can be done using openCv.Could u please provide some links if u know about how to compare faces in Android and check for their similarity?

Comment: There's no need to thank me, just up vote the answer. You should start by reading the official [Face Recognition with OpenCV - Tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html).